# How to change the xml properties from default properties?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

[image]

The above screen capture shows the expected output and actual output, red color indicates that it differs from the actual output that is shown in green color.

To create xml document I have used the marshall concept.Java code used to create xml document are given below.

```
 import com.ehf.bean.Invoice;
 import com.sap._0050089212_one_off.ypt74nkey_.StandardFaultMessage;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
 import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
 import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
 import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
 import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

 public class Ehf {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, 
 TransformerException, SAXException, IOException, StandardFaultMessage, 
 com.sap.xi.a1s.global.StandardFaultMessage, JAXBException {

    JAXBContext contextObj = JAXBContext.newInstance(Invoice.class);

    Marshaller marshallerObj = contextObj.createMarshaller();
    marshallerObj.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    invoice.setCustomizationID("dsf");
    invoice.setInvoiceTypeCode(0);
    marshallerObj.marshal(invoice, new FileOutputStream("question.xml"));

}

}
```

**Note: Invoice  class is generated using xsd, through xjc command.**

How can resolve this problem?

Comment: The two shown XML snippets are technically equivalent. So what is your problem?

Comment: Side note: Even XML is text. Don't post them as images.

Comment: In dont want xmlns prefix ns3 how can remove ?

Comment: The real question is: _Why do you want to do that?_ And any parser/transformer is able to do that.

Comment: because I have the requirement that should same as expected output and now finally I found the way to change, thanks for the information

Comment: As I already said: Both XML are equivalent. No need to change the textual representation for any technical reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
namespace = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2", 
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
xmlns ={@XmlNs(prefix="cac", namespaceURI="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"), 
        @XmlNs(prefix="cbc", namespaceURI="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"),
        @XmlNs(prefix="", namespaceURI="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2")
       })
```

The above code is working for me as expected, this code should be write in **package-info.java**